# Weak convergence of solution

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I'm trying to figure out why in this paper:
[Asymptotic convergence of semigroups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123675900270)

In the proof of theorem 1, I don't understand why $\{x(t):t\geq0\}$ is weakly sequentially precompact and why this should mean that for two $(*)$-sequences $(t_n)$ and $(s_n)$, $x(t_n)$ and $x(s_n)$ converge to some weak limit.

Could someone explain in detail? Thank you

Comment: You cannot expect an answer unless you tell us where exactly you have problem with the proofs in that article.

Comment: You're right! I thought I said the theorem I'm referring to. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x : [0,\infty) \to H$ is continuous, and it was shown that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \|x(t)-y_0\|$ exists, then in particular, $\{x(t) : t \ge 0\}$ is bounded in norm.  So by Alaoglu's theorem, it is weakly compact.

This also implies weak sequential compactness.  Indeed, if $H$ is separable then any bounded set is weakly metrizable, so then weak compactness and weak sequential compactness are equivalent.  If $H$ is not separable, then given a sequence $\{x(t_n)\}$, consider the separable subspace $H' \subset H$ consisting of the closed linear span of $\{x(t_n)\}$.  Then by the previous case there is a subsequence converging weakly in $H'$, which thus also converges weakly in $H$.

After that, I think you're misreading the sentence around (1.5).  What is being asserted in this sentence (and what the rest of the proof goes on to show) is the conditional statement that ***if*** $x(t_n)$ and $x(s_n)$ both converge weakly ***then*** their limits must be equal.

To see why this assertion (call it A) implies the claim that $x(t_n)$ converges weakly, use the "double subsequence trick".  Suppose it did not.  Weak compactness says there is a subsequence $t_{n_k}$ (which is also a (*)-sequence) with $x(t_{n_k})$ converging weakly to some $x^*$.  Since the original sequence $x(t_n)$ did not converge weakly to $x^*$ or anything else, there is a weakly open neighborhood $U$ of $x^*$ and a subsequence $t_{m_k}$ such that all $x(t_{m_k})$ are outside $U$.  This subsequence has a further subsequence converging weakly to some $x^{**}$, which is necessarily outside $U$ and in particular not equal to $x^*$.  But this contradicts the assertion A.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the weak sequential compactness DOES NOT directly imply that for every (*)-sequence $(t_n)$ the sequence $x(t_n)$ converge, right? You have to use necessarily the double subsequence trick, am I right?

Comment: @Paolo: Right.  You can obviously think of sequences in sequentially compact spaces that fail to converge (e.g. in $[0,1]$, the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$).  But such a sequence always has at least one limit point.  What remains, in this case, is to show that it has at most one.